# How to write edit function using -react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my page when i click the button then it is show detail (see the below image 
[image]

This is edit page:
[image]

my problem is when I try to edit the details (see the edit details image).it should take the values(id) like below image.But when I click the edit button those input fields not show existing details .how can I do this .please help me for this error ?
[image]

This is my edit details form coding i used back-end loopback,database mysql :

```
 <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} layout="inline">

            <FormItem {...formItemLayout} label="Title" >
                {getFieldDecorator('Title', {
                  rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please provide Title!' },{ max: 15, message: 'Title should maximum 15 characters ' },
                /* { pattern: '(^[A-Z][a-z]*$)', message: ' Please Start with Uppercase' }*/],
                })(
             <Select  prefix={<Icon type="book" style={{ fontSize: 13 }} />} 
              showSearch
              style={{ width: 65 }}
              placeholder="Mr."
              optionFilterProp="children"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              onFocus={this.handleFocus}
              onBlur={this.handleBlur}
              filterOption={(input, option) => option.props.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0}
            >

            <Option value="Mr.">Mr.</Option>
              <Option value="Ms.">Ms.</Option>
              <Option value="Miss.">Miss.</Option>

            </Select>


                )}
              </FormItem>

              <FormItem {...formItemLayout} label="Name" >
                {getFieldDecorator('Name', {
                  rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please provide name!' },{ max: 15, message: 'Name should maximum 15 characters ' },
                  /* { pattern: '(^[A-Z][a-z]*$)', message: ' Please Start with Uppercase' }*/],
                })(
                  <Input  prefix={<Icon type="user" style={{ fontSize: 13 }} />} placeholder="Name" />
                )}
              </FormItem>


              <FormItem
              {...formItemLayout}
              label="Relation :"
            >
             {getFieldDecorator('Relation', {
                rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please provide relation!' }, { max: 200, message: 'Note should be within a 200 characters' }],
              })(

           <Select  prefix={<Icon type="book" style={{ fontSize: 13 }} />} 

              showSearch
              style={{ width: 150 }}
              placeholder="Select a Relation"
              optionFilterProp="children"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              onFocus={this.handleFocus}
              onBlur={this.handleBlur}
              filterOption={(input, option) => option.props.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0}
            >


            <Option value="Father ">Father</Option>
              <Option value="Mother ">Mother</Option>
              <Option value="Husband ">Husband</Option>
              <Option value="Wife ">Wife</Option>
              <Option value="Brother">Brother</Option>
              <Option value="Sister">Sister</Option>
              <Option  value=" Other">  <Input placeholder="Other"  style={{ marginLeft:-7,width: 140,height:32 }} type="text"/> </Option>

            </Select>
            )}


            </FormItem>

            <FormItem
              {...formItemLayout}
              label="Contact No :"
            >
              {getFieldDecorator('Telephone_no', {
                rules: [{
                  required: true, message: 'Please input contact number!',
                }, { max: 10, message: 'You can only add 10 numbers' }, { pattern: '^[0-9]\\d{0,9}?%?$', message: 'Should be a number' },{ min: 10, message: 'You can not add less than 10 numbers' } ],
              })(
                <Input prefix={<Icon type="phone" style={{ fontSize: 13 }} />} placeholder="Contact No" style={{ width: 150 }} />

              )}
            </FormItem>

               <FormItem label="Address:" {...formItemLayout}>
              {getFieldDecorator('Address', {
                rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please provide address!' }, { max: 100, message: 'Note should be within a 100 characters' }],
              })(
                <TextArea  prefix={<Icon type="book" style={{ fontSize: 13 }} />} placeholder="Address ...?" style={{ width: 350 ,height:75 ,marginTop: 20 ,marginLeft: 33} } />
              )}
            </FormItem>

            <FormItem >
              <Row>
                <Button type="primary"   icon="check-circle-o" htmlType="submit"  style={{ marginLeft: 85,marginTop: 40 }}/>
                <Button htmlType="reset" icon="close-circle" style={{ marginLeft:8 ,marginTop: 40}} onClick={this.resetFields} />
                <Button htmlType="reset" onClick={this.cancelEdit} icon="close-circle" style={{ marginLeft: 8 }}>Cancel</Button>

              </Row>
            </FormItem>
        </Form>
```

Comment: The title of your question doesn't really match the content. It seems like your issue is with having the form reflect values that currently exist in the database. If that's the case, you should be passing those values in via `props` and setting the `value` prop on your fields.

Comment: @NorianNyx I change it sir.. could you please correct my code?

Comment: It looks like you're using a library for your forms. Something like `redux-form`? If it's `redux-form` then look into [this](https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/examples/initializefromstate/).